# Expect: what is the meaning of "force_conservative", "set send_slow" and "--"?

Tags: expect

```
set force_conservative 1  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
              ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}
```

I dont understand what `force_conservative` does and also the statments like
 `set send_slow {1 .1}` inside proc send are not clear to me.

also why is `--` is needed for send command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish with this script, but here is the answers.

`force_conservative` parameter makes expect script to pause for one tenth of a second before sending each character. It is done so your shell will not ignore characters that came to quickly.

`set send_slow {1 .1}` will do the same thing. It will make a 100ms pause (second parameter) every 1 symbol (first parameter).

```
proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
}
```

This code snippet is doing basically the same thing as the previous two. The `--` parameters used to tell your script that you will add no more options, it is options delimiter.